# Liferay Security PermissionsURL: Preventing page refresh on save

Tags: permissions, liferay, alloy-ui

I'm currently showing a permissionsURL in an AUI Dialog box, and every time I click save the whole page reloads, showing just the permissions page (since the window state is POP_UP).

Is there a way to make the permissions page not refresh when I click the save button (like in the assets configuration page)?

Comment: Tell me if I understand correctly, You want to open a pop-up on click of a link and then you want to enter inputs in the form field and click submit. After the submit, only the pop-up should get refreshed leaving the parent page as it is.

Comment: yes, that is right, but the page I'm displaying in the pop up is not coded by me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use AUI Dialog **Iframe** instead of just an AUI dialog box.

Here is sample code as to how to use a **dialog-iframe** component instead of just aui-dialog:

```
Liferay.provide( // liferay's way of writing a function
        window,
        '<portlet:namespace />openCustomDialog', //function name
        function(url, popupID) { // parameters to the function
            var A = AUI();

            popupDialog = new A.Dialog(
                {
                    id: popupID, // popupId passed so that it would be easy to close it through events other than the close button
                    centered: true, // all the different parameters function you can check in the Alloy API
                    draggable: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    width: 800,
                    stack: true,
                    modal: true
                }
            ).plug(
                A.Plugin.DialogIframe,
                {
                    uri: url,
                    iframeCssClass: 'dialog-iframe, my-custom-css-class'
                }
            );

            popupDialog.render();
        },
        ['aui-dialog','aui-dialog-iframe']
    );
```

This will open a dialog and create an iframe then will load your page inside an iframe. So the permissions page in a sense becomes independent of the parent page. So whatever you do with the permissions page even if you submit only the pop-up will refresh.

See if this helps.